# How do I convert between enums for passing between different functions

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development

I have enums set up in a script called Grid, as follows:

```
public enum CellType
{
    Empty,
    Road,
    Structure,
    SpecialStructure,
    None
}
```

Then I have a script called placement manager which adds data relevant to that enum like this:

```
internal void PlaceObjectOnTheMap(Vector3Int position, GameObject structurePrefab, CellType type, int width = 1, int height = 1)
    {
        StructureModel structure = CreateANewStructureModel(position, structurePrefab, type);

    var structureNeedingRoad = structure.GetComponent<INeedingRoad>();
    if (structureNeedingRoad != null)
    {
        structureNeedingRoad.RoadPosition = GetNearestRoad(position, width, height).Value;
        Debug.Log("My nearest road position is: " + structureNeedingRoad.RoadPosition);
    }

    for (int x = 0; x < width; x++)
    {
        for (int z = 0; z < height; z++)
        {
            var newPosition = position + new Vector3Int(x, 0, z);
            placementGrid[newPosition.x, newPosition.z] = type;
            structureDictionary.Add(newPosition, structure);
            DestroyNatureAt(newPosition);
        }
    }

}
```

finally, I have another script called Grid Helper which is supposed to call placement manager and add itself to the grid which I've set like this:

```
public enum CellType
    {
        Empty,
        Road,
        Structure,
        SpecialStructure,
        None
    }
    [SerializeField]
    private CellType structureType = CellType.Empty;

public PlacementManager placementManager;
// Start is called before the first frame update
void Start()
{
    placementManager.PlaceObjectOnTheMap(new Vector3Int(Mathf.FloorToInt(transform.position.x),
        Mathf.FloorToInt(transform.position.y),
        Mathf.FloorToInt(transform.position.z)), this.gameObject, structureType);
}
```

but I somehow keep getting told Argument3 cannot convert from GridHelper.CellType to CellType.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Do not define the CellType enum again in the grid helper. Just don't do it. Keep only a _single_ definition of the CellType enum in your project.

Comment: @MySkullCaveIsADarkPlace but I want to be able to set it in the editor from my GridHelper

Comment: I don't know much about the Unity editor, but re-declaring the enum twice or more in your project is not the correct way to solve your problem with the editor. The developers of the Unity editor are not so incompetent to make the editor in a way that it would require re-declaring the same enums multiple times within the same project just to make the editor work properly with scripts...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove your enum in the GridHelper or in the Grid class and use GridHelper.CellType or Grid.CellType in the other class depending on what you removed.